# What technology would you use for random queries with constraints on data?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, bigdata, data-warehouse

I need to extract data semi-randomly, that is a random item, but in a certain subset of the data. And need to do this several times.

My first approach is to use Postgres `ORDER BY random()` and filter with `WHERE` statements, but that performs poorly.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be Postgres?  Random sampling in R is easy and flexible, you can choose a particular probability for each ítem in the subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Elasticsearch through Tire (Ruby gem). The performance, with right indexing, made page loading time go from 30+ seconds to <1s (and independent from DB size).

Example:

```
Recipe.search do |search|
    search.sort do |sort|
      sort.by({
        _script: { 
          script: "Math.random()",
          type: "number",
          params: {},
          order: "asc"
        }
      })
    end

    search.size 1
end
```

Which generates:

```
{
"sort": [{
    "_script": {
        "script": "Math.random()",
        "type": "number",
        "params": {},
        "order": "asc"
    }
}],
"size": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `order by random()` if you use something like:

```
select * from table where [your conditions] and random()>.9
```

This will select approx 90% of rows matching all other conditions. However, I'm not sure whether this will improve performance.

Another strategy:

1. Add column with random numbers between 1 and 1000 to your data (e.g. using name randc)
2. Create index on this column
3. Use something like `select * from table where [your conditions] and randc > 900`

Because numbers are random, there is still good chance that approx 90% from rows matching your conditions will be selected.